# Are there tools I can use to get an automated javascript profile of an automated test?

Tags: gratis, web-apps, web-development, javascript, web-browser

I  want to create tests for example using selenium to go to a website and do various tasks there. Then I want to be able to have a javascript cpu profile, or a performance report once the test concludes. What are other tools I can use other than automating clicking to the "Dev tools" of a browser and then clicking "save"?

I looked at phantomjs and specifically confess.js but the report is done of a page that has been loaded. I want to analyze other tasks and not just a page load.

Comment: Using nodejs you could create your own, but it would be limited to node.js environment and there's no DOM. You can use zombie.js but the rendering time wouldn't be included then, because zombie.js doesn't do any rendering.